# Improvements to the StackExchange Global Profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, network-profile

I recently found out that a StackExchange profile page has been created. While I really like it that there is a page, there could be a few improvements that would make the page much more useful as right now its a bit anemic.

Note that I'm approaching all of this with the assumption that someone has linked their stackexchange profile somewhere and a random person clicks it. They want the most relevant information on the very first page (most people aren't going to dive into the accounts page)

- **Show Global Reputation** - This is the first thing that would really make the profile useful: How much total reputation do I have?
- **Show reputation of the 3 most active sites** - I'm in a bunch of SE sites, but which one's am I the most active in? This could also draw a non-SO user into joining the network since they can say "Well this person has 11,000 reputation on SO, what is SO and why does this programmer have such a high reputation there?" Perhaps even the reputation percentage jump visible on your profile could be shown as well.
- <s>**Advertise that there's a Global profile to the user** - For the user that has the profile, there's no indication that there *is* a global profile. The only link to it is if the user clicks their flair image. There really should be something that says "Hey, you have a global profile!" and not just a linked image</s> This has been added recently to the user profile page, which is about as obvious as it will ever be.
- **Improve the question list** - What about number of views (others will wonder why a question got 10,000 views), number of answers, and weather there is an accepted answer? As a side note, why is there so much padding between the questions and between the questions and the tag? All the other sites have the question layout very tight.

Implementing these would make the SE page much more useful and I would change my existing SE flair links to point to this page vs my Programmers Profile which I think says more about me.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the third bullet, but it's linked just like any site profile: you click your display name at the top of http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Michael But for those of us who don't regularly visit stackexchange.com (which I think is a lot of people), there is no indication.

Comment: Oh, so a link on every SE site? Ok

Comment: > "`Show Global Reputation`" - use your global Flair badge in your profile, like I do: https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/137942.png - The FavIcon for your top sites appear there, you can make the image a link to your global profile too.