# Add a link to Global SE Profile on user's profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com

I think that it'd be nice to just have a link to people's global SE profile on their account page, especially with all the spiffy new changes. Currently, they're basically impossible to find without a direct link because you can't search for them and no one posts on SE.com so you can't click that link.

Just something simple like this would do nicely:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improvements to the StackExchange Global Profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81816/improvements-to-the-stackexchange-global-profile)

Comment: Item #3: Advertise that there's a Global profile to the user

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi: I saw that, but this isn't just for your own, but to let you see other people's also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: behold!]

We've added such a link (for user's who have associated accounts).

We're also making some improvements to that profile, so stay tuned for those.  Already completed is a [network-wide activity page](https://stackexchange.com/users/5f55f8fb-d712-43bf-99c9-9626b0b2210d?tab=activity).

Comment: Nicely nicely! Now with this easier access to the profile and since the profile is on the plate now, [any thoughts on the topic of profile selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81750/allow-users-to-set-the-base-profile-that-your-stackexchange-com-profile-inherit)?

Comment: @Grace Note - first, let us finish making the profile worth visiting by default.  Then we'll revisit customizing it.

Comment: Sounds excellent to me. Thanks for the quick feedback. ♪