# Aggregate activity replicates edit activities that affect more than one part of a post

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stackexchange.com, activity-summary

The global profile on stackexchange.com boasts a new Activity functionality, announced just earlier this week.

There's an issue, though. It treats edits to titles, bodies, and tags as separate entities, thus rendering 2-3 entries for any edit that affects multiple elements of one post. As with elsewhere on the network that this issue has been fixed, it should probably only render a single event per post.

[image: Image of replicated entries.]

Comment: I wonder if this is related to it showing my 5 favorite changes today, when there was only 2 or 3?  If not on revisions, then maybe it's stacking answers.

Comment: I'm curious what "announced just earlier this week" refers to - I actually didn't even know about this global profile. Is it mentioned in the "Recent feature changes"?

Comment: @Hendrik http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85561/add-a-link-to-global-se-profile-on-users-profile/85920#85920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fixed](https://stackexchange.com/users/30498037-168a-4055-a849-0c31c2b1d863?tab=activity).

[image]