# Network profile should list total reputation and badges across the network

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges, profile-page, network-profile

Looking at your network profile, there is no number anywhere in your entire profile that has a sum of all your reputation across the network except for the flair page, which isn't always accurate because it's cached, and isn't exact because it rounds. Yet, there's so much empty space on the profile page.

My simple idea is to list the user's total reputation and badge counts below their Gravatar image like on any normal profile page across the network (keeping the rule of only accounts with over 200 reputation). It would make it incredibly easy to find and I wouldn't have to go search for myself on Area 51 to figure it out.

[image: Example in not-so-professional looking red freehand text.]

Comment: Related: [Display combined rep total on Stack Exchange users reputation page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87774)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81816/improvements-to-the-stackexchange-global-profile

Comment: By the way: You can also find your global reputation on your chat account.

Comment: Now that you're inside the team, maybe give this some internal bump? :-)

Comment: I was about to ask a similar question. It'd be great to see total of questions, answers and people reached, like in profile, except that it'd be network wide.

Answer (score 9):

I agree that the network profile should show the network totals -- the same way the chat profile already does.  Whatever rules are used for tallying that up for the chat profile should be used for the network profile too, for consistency.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative can be adding the flair in the description of one of the networks such as

[image]

For that, there's an `HTML` code, that SO makes available, that one can add to the description of the communities. In order to grab the `HTML` code access the tab Flair in the Network. In my case the direct link looks like the following https://stackexchange.com/users/9572673/gon%c3%a7alo-peres-%e9%be%9a%e7%87%bf%e7%a6%84?tab=flair

Then copy the code bellow the following text

> How do I use it?
> Simply copy and paste the below HTML snippet wherever you want to show off your combined Stack Exchange flair:

In my case it is the following

`<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/9572673/goncalo-peres"><img src="https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/9572673.png?theme=clean" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for Goncalo Peres on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for Goncalo Peres on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" /></a>`

And added that code to the description of the community that I will be using to define the Network description. Then Update profile description based on that specific community by pressing "Update profile info" under the description section.

[image]

A pop-up will appear and all one has to do is select the community where one added the code for the flair in the description.

Answer (score 0):

In [my case](https://stackexchange.com/users/30810/arjan?tab=accounts) it would not show a useful figure, I feel. I have more reputation on MSE than on any site that actually matters. Hence, the 34k on my flair really does not represent any useful number, I feel, while peeking in the actual list gives one a much better idea.

So: what about not only applying the 200 rep rule, but also exclude MSE? Maybe some others too?

(If I would be using flair, I would like MSE [to be excluded from that too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128466/id-like-network-flair-to-allow-selection-of-included-stack-exchange-sites). The network profile is different though: others might see it when I am not promoting it myself.)

Comment: I know I'm not in the majority, but I don't consider MSO reps necessarily any less valuable than reps on any other site. Granted, it's certainly possible to post relatively worthless stuff here and receive reps anyway, but it's not like you can't provide answers that require just as much effort as they would on other sites in the network. Then again, I have more Meta reps than all other reps combined, so perhaps I'm just biased.

Comment: MSE might not matter to you but it does matter to others.  It should not be excluded.