# View users aggregate reputation on all SE sites

Tags: support, reputation

Is there any way to view a user's total reputation on all their SE profiles? I know the SE [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447978/davidsbro/flair) gives a rough estimate (since sites with over 200 rep are only counted). However, it can take a while to navigate to different users' flairs. I'm asking because I'm wondering if any users have 1M rep in aggregate yet (since I know some are getting close on SO alone). I've looked at the [top](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) SO users' aggregates (via their flair), but it would take a while to see all the other >200k users. So basically, is there a way to view a user's all-time StackExchange rep?

If there isn't a way to view the rep added up, just out of curiosity, are there any users with 1M rep? Is Jon Skeet probably going to be the first there?

Comment: I don't think there are ways other than flair and chat profile, both of which can't be searched with reputation in mind.

Comment: I just found this:http://stackapps.com/questions/2575/stack-exchange-reputation-graph-total-reputation-overlay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but you can go to the Stack Exchange account page of a user.

Just go to their profile page, click the "network profile" link:

> [image: network profile]

Then on the Stack Exchange account page, click "accounts".

All their accounts, with reputation is listed there, though not rolled up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize you can do that, I was wondering if there was some way to view the rep "rolled up".

Comment: @davidsbro - no, there isn't.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So I have two questions if you don't mind. 1. Does any user have 1M rep? and 2. Wouldn't it be fairly easy to have something on the network profile that adds the rep up? (Unless something changes, I accept your answer when I'm allowed to in 9 minutes)

Comment: @davidsbro [Network profile should list total reputation and badges across the network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136425/network-profile-should-list-total-reputation-and-badges-across-the-network)

Comment: @davidsbro - I have no idea if there are any such users. Frankly, aggregate reputation doesn't mean much, so why have it? And as for easy - possibly. But for a meaningless metric?

Comment: @animuson, thanks for that link. I hope the SE team implements your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get currently is browsing the [chat.SE users, sorted by reputation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=reputation).

[image: StackExchange chat all users, sorted by reputation]

Comment: Go to the network account page of Jon Skeet. The number on chat doesn't even come close (ie. add up the first **two** reps - the number on chat is much less than that).

Comment: @Oded you're right, why is that?

Comment: Different chat servers - Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow and the rest of the network have different chat servers.

Comment: @Oded But my chat profile counts the rep from all sites where I have over 200 rep (incl. MSO and SO)?

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure...

Comment: @Oded [Caching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224872/230957) (in case you missed it & for future readers)