# Why does chat profile reputation seem inconsistent?

Tags: support, reputation, chat

The reputation on [chat.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com) is supposed to be [all your 200+ rep accounts' reputation combined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175036/230957). Now why is it that [Jon Skeet](https://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=accounts)'s [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/11757/jon-skeet) **does not include his MSO reputation**, but otherwise includes all 200+ rep accounts' reputation (including SO, of course)?

[My chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/85308/3ventic) *does* include all my 200+ rep accounts *including MSO*.

Comment: The question came from the [comments on this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224854/230957).

Comment: Caching! It's always caching. He hasn't logged in in so long chat probably hasn't bothered with picking up his full account associations, or something.

Comment: Caching is the most likely answer tbh, as the rep totals for Skeet's accounts excluding MSO don't reach the chat rep, but including MSO go way over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I refreshed his chat profile from the parent site and that updated the rep to add up to whatever it is supposed to be right now.

There's no particular mystery here. Just the usual. :)